# My application has stopped sending tweets with images

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter

I have an Android application that uses the option to share in Android. The application worked fine to post a tweet, but recently stopped publishing the tweet giving an error. The error reason I have it located. My application downloads an image, which is attached to the tweet. That image is stored in a temporary folder and deleted when the onActivityResult method is called. Twitter is now calling this method before posting the tweet, therefore when you try to post the picture, it has already been removed.
Any suggestions on this? Is this something that will change in a Twitter update, or should I modify my application?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
private void sendShareTwit() {
    try {
        Intent tweetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        String filename = "<file path>/twitter_image.jpg";
        File imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename);

        tweetIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, twitter_share_text);
        tweetIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
        tweetIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
        PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> lract = pm.queryIntentActivities(tweetIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        boolean resolved = false;
        for (ResolveInfo ri : lract) {
            if (ri.activityInfo.name.contains("twitter")) {
                tweetIntent.setClassName(ri.activityInfo.packageName,
                        ri.activityInfo.name);
                resolved = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        startActivity(resolved ?
                tweetIntent :
                Intent.createChooser(tweetIntent, "Choose one"));
    } catch (final ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.rintln( "You don't seem to have twitter installed on this device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT));
    }
}
```